# Use Docker and docker compose with the Spring Boot REST app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I've been reading about the Docker and how to use it to run the Spring app. I read that in case of Docker, we use the  Docker engine ( instead of guest OS) which is a very thin layer of the OS, and the container can talk down into the host OS in order to get to the kernel functionality there. And that allows us to have a very lightweight container.

This kind of make sense.

I would like to have a very basic setup and use the Docker for the `Spring Boot` and `MySQL` app I'm developing. The app runs itself fine (without Docker).  The project structure is provided,

[image]

First I run the `$ mvn clean package`

This creates the `Appointment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the `/target` directory.

[image]

I define the Dockerfile afterward reading a tutorial,

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/Appointment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Appointment.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /Appointment.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/Appointment.jar"]
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` file provided below,

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - logvolume01:/var/log

  appointment-mysql:
      container_name: appointment-mysql
      image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Appointment
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpassword
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      ports:
      - "3307:3307"
      restart: always

volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

I intionally chnage the port for the MySQL to the 3307. Finally, I run the command,

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

I get the output message,

```
appointment-mysql is up-to-date
Starting appointmentmanager_web_1 ... done
```

I see nothing happens afterward. Would anyone please provide a clear instruction about how do I run a Spring boot app with the Docker and docker-compose?

Clearly, I don't get any error message, but, normally when I run the app, 
a method is called and load a bunch of data in the database.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AppointmentApplication.class, args);
        loadAppointmentsData();
    }
```

and I can use the `cURL` to do various queries for the app. It seems something is missing. I know its late to learn and use the Docker, I really appreciate if someone helps me to get started using the Docker with the Spring Boot app.

**UPDATE**

I try the command `docker-compose up` (without -d) and it seems I have few errors,

```
$ docker-compose up
appointment-mysql is up-to-date
Starting appointmentmanager_web_1 ... done
Attaching to appointment-mysql, appointmentmanager_web_1
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.25-1.1.10
appointment-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.25-1.1.10
web_1                | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
web_1                | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
web_1                | [INFO] Total time: 0.205 s
web_1                | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-12T14:33:03Z
web_1                | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
web_1                | [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
web_1                | [ERROR] 
web_1                | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
web_1                | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
web_1                | [ERROR] 
web_1                | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
web_1                | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
appointmentmanager_web_1 exited with code 1
```

I assumed this is related to the `pom.xml` file configuration, so, I also provided that below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appoint.manager</groupId>
    <artifactId>Appointment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Appointment</name>
    <description>A project for Appointment Management</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.17.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>-->

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So think the error is mainly described below and this is `No goals have been specified`

```
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

Comment: You see nothing happening because you run docker-compose up in [detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/compose/reference/up/) `-d`. Removing this option will lock your terminal while the containers are running but you have more verbose on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probleme? your application seem to be running, test it like you use to do without docker (test the healthcheck if it's a rest api)

and see logs of your container if you have an error stack

Comment: I usually test the app via the `cURL`. Now when I tried to use, I get the message,

`$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"created_at\" : \"01:12:16\",\"appointment_date\" : \"2018-10-05\",\"name_of_doctor\" : \"Monika\", \"price\": \"122.5\"}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/createAppointment
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Comment: and for the port of `3307`

`$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"created_at\" : \"01:12:16\",\"appointment_date\" : \"2018-10-05\",\"name_of_doctor\" : \"Monika\", \"price\": \"122.5\"}" http://localhost:3307/api/v1/appointments/createAppointment
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: Do you know if all the configurations are correct or how to test the app property? Also, I put a bunch of the JSON data in the MySQL at the time the app starts, which seems didn't work in the case.

Comment: ok but if your application run on port 8080 you have to open the port 8080 of your container to be accessible. in your docker compose for the web service why did you put 5000:5000 on your opening port and not 8080:8080 ?

Comment: I changed the ports in the `docker-compose.yaml` file and `$ mvn clean package` again. Afterwards, I run the command `$ docker-compose up -d` and tried to test via the `cURL`. I get the message in the terminal `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`. 

So my conclusion is changing the port had no affect in my case.

Comment: if you change the docker compose, you should run docker-compose stop, remove containers (docker ps to list them, docker rm to remove yours) then run docker-compose up, otherwise your changes are not taken effect.

Comment: I just did that and it's still the same.

Comment: ok i have seen your changes... your pom should containe the docker plugin, check on the web but the spotify is a good one. and then build your image using mvn clean package docker:build (remove the line builds in your docker-compose instead put the line image : yourNameImage:latest to get your last build image.

Comment: I use the docker plugin and I get the error `[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build.` though  I did have a goal `<build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory></build>` in the `pom.xml` file.   and What's the `yourNameImage` here? I try to follow you but I wasn't able to pursue further